# Community user login successfully and show a web page instead of Salesforce Mobile SDK home page

Tags: community, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk

I am developing a react native app by using salesforce mobile sdk, and there is a problem for community user login.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Community user login through the specific url.
2. Login successfully, shows its web home page.

Expected:

1. Community user login through the specific url.
2. Login successfully, shows mobile app home page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Issues resolved.
I previously used a web login url in mobile app, like `https://training-test.cs111.force.com/red/s`.
But the thing is we should use `https://training-test.cs111.force.com/red`, without the tailing path `/s`.